# Produce Lists with Parallel Stream

Tags: java, list, merge, parallel-processing, stream

I have a list of Json Strings, which contain lists of **movies**. I need to collect those movies, process them and store them in the disk. I am thinking of using a parallel stream method to collect the movies and test its performance. My approach is this:

The following method produces a **List of Movies**.

```
protected abstract List<T> parseJsonString(JsonIterator iter);
```

This method contains a parallel stream that collects a **List of all Lists** ( `List<List<Movies)` ) produced in the stream:

```
public CompletableFuture<List<List<T>>> parseJsonPages(List<CompletableFuture<String>> jsonPageList)
{
    return jsonPageList.parallelStream()
            .map( jsonPageStr -> CompletableFuture.supplyAsync( () -> {
                try {
                    return parseJsonString(JsonIterator.parse( jsonPageStr.get() ) );
                }
                catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    System.exit(-1);
                }
                return null;
            } ) )
            .collect( ParallelCollectors.toFuture( Collectors.toList() ) );
}
```

The problem with this approach is that the stream will produce the lists of movies and then append all lists inside a list. Do You think this is an effective way of collecting all those movies? Should I merge the movies from all lists in one list, instead of just appending the entire lists inside a list (even though this also costs some time). If so, How do I perform such task?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you read [When to use Parallel Streams](http://gee.cs.oswego.edu/dl/html/StreamParallelGuidance.html)?

Comment: @EdwinDalorzo The article You send me says:


"Consider using S.parallelStream().operation(F) instead of S.stream().operation(F) when operations are independent, and either computationally expensive or applied to many elements of efficiently splittable data structures, or both".

Parsing each of those strings is obviously independent. Also, It takes a lot of computational time to parse json objects only from a string. I have 1000+ Json Strings. Also, I am trying to test the theoretic performance of this approach, not just count seconds...

Answer (score 1):

## Project Loom

In the future, when [Project Loom](https://wiki.openjdk.java.net/display/loom/Main) arrives with its virtual threads, it will be much simpler and likely much faster execution to simply assign each task to a virtual thread.

[Preliminary builds](http://jdk.java.net/loom/) of Project Loom are available now, built on early-access Java 16. Though subject to change, and not ready for production, if this is a non-mission-critical personal project, you might consider using it now.

By the way, your `Movie` class might be suitable to define as a [record](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/395), one of the features coming in Java 16.

```java
List< String > inputListsOfMoviesAsJson = … ;  // Input.
Set< Movie > movies = Set.of() ;  // Output. Default to unmodifiable empty `Set`. 
try 
(
    ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newVirtualThreadExecutor() ;
)
{
    movies = Collections.synchronizedSet( new HashSet< Movie > ) ;
    for( String inputJson : inputListsOfMoviesAsJson )
    {
        Runnable task = () -> movies.addAll( this.parseJsonIntoSetOfMovies( inputJson ) ) ;
        executorService.submit( task ) ;
    }
}
// At this point, flow-of-control blocks until all tasks are done.
// Then the executor service is automatically shutdown as part of being closed, as an `AutoCloseable` in a try-with-resources.
… use your `Set` of `Movie` objects.
```

If you want to track success/failure, then capture and collect the `Future` object returned by each call to `executorService.submit( task )`. The code above ignores that return value, for simplicity of the demo.

As to your Question about accumulating a list, of resulting `Movie` objects versus merging later, I do not think collecting those objects will be a bottleneck. My guess is that processing JSON will be the bottleneck. Either way, using profiler tools to verify your actual bottlenecks will likely be easier with the simpler coding possible when using Project Loom.

In code above, I use a `Set` made thread-safe by a call to `Collections.synchronized…`. You could try various implementations of `Set` or `List`. A list might be faster, but a set has the benefit of eliminating duplicates if that is an issue in your data inputs.

### Caveats

#### Memory

This approach assumes you have plenty of memory to handle all the JSON work. With virtual threads, all of those inputs might be getting processed at nearly the same time.

- In Project Loom, a blocked virtual thread is “parked”, moved aside for another thread to run. So you can have many virtual threads running, even millions.
- With conventional platform/kernel threads, a blocked thread does *not* make way for another thread to start working. So you have few threads running at one time.

So if memory is a constrained resource, you’ll need to take further measures to prevent too many virtual threads from starting the JSON processing.

#### CPU-bound tasks

Virtual threads (fibers) are appropriate for work that involves blocking code. For purely CPU-bound tasks such as video-encoding, conventional platform/kernel threads are best. If you are doing nothing but processing JSON text already loaded into memory, then virtual threads may not show a benefit if they turn out to be CPU-bound. But I’d give it a try, as a test run is so easy. If you are doing any I/O (logging, accessing files, hitting a database, making network calls) then you will definitely see dramatic performance improvements with virtual threads.

#### Related code must be thread-safe

Be sure your JSON processing library is built to be thread-safe.

And be sure your `parseJsonIntoSetOfMovies` method is thread-safe.

## Recommended reading

Read the book, *Java Concurrency In Practice* by Brian Goetz et al.